# I have installed mongodb locally, how do i get its data synced with mongodb server or cluster?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

> This piece of code i used to connect to specific database in MongoDB locally.

```
    const express = require('express');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const app = express();

    const connectionString = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/user-manager';

    // Database
    mongoose.connect(connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
     .then(() => console.log('Connected to Database...'))
     .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

> Here is User Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: { type: String, required: true },
    lastname: { type: String, required: false },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    age: { type: String, required: true },
    team: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

> I want my locally saved database, collections, and data to be available at MongoDB Atlas too.

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use the live migrate utility available in the atlas.

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/live-import/index.html

This will migrate the complete data from your local MongoDB deployment to the Atlas cluster.